# Simple messages system between user and admin with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've created simple message system between user and admin. When user report some item I have storing his report and then admin has button 'Replay to user' for this report.

I think I messed something with database tables and relations so please help me understand this.

So I have table `reports` with columns + example data ( two users reported same item )

```
report_id | user_id | item_id
    1          1        1
    1          2        1
```

This table holds reports from user(user_id) to given item(item_id). Then I have table called `reports_messages` with columns + example of replays between both users and admin

```
report_id | user_id | item_id | messages
    1          1         1       Report
    1        admin       1       answer from admin
    1          2         1       Report from other user
    1        admin       1       answer from admin to other user
```

This is my `ReportMessages` model

```
class ReportMessages extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'reports_messages';

     protected $fillable = [
         'report_id', 'user_id', 'messages', 'item_id'
     ];

     public function reports(){

         return $this->belongsTo('App\Report');
     }

     public function users()
     {
         return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
     }  
}
```

In admin controller this is how I display all reports for given item_id

```
public function details( $item_id ){

    $flags = Item::find($item_id)->report->unique('user_id');
    return view('details', compact('flags'));
}
```

button replay to user

```
<a href="{{URL::to('replays/' . collect($flags)->first()->item_id)}}">Replay To User</a>
```

And route

```
Route::get('details/{details}', 'FlagsController@details')->name('details');
```

Problem: When I have 2 users reported same item and I click on Replay to user button I get messages of both user no matter which one I opened.

I know that the problem i probably the button because I added `collect($flags)->first()->item_id` which gives me item ID not user ID but I can't figured out the relations here and how when I click to replay to user with id=1 to load only his messages.

Update: Item model

```
public function report(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Report', 'item_id','id');
}
```

Comment: Did you make a relation with Item model? So you can add user_id and item_id to reply to user link

Comment: Yes, I have relation and I've tried link like: `<' href="{{URL::to('replays/' . collect($flags)->first()->item_id .'/' . $flag->user->id)}}">Replay To User</a>` But when I make it like this I get messages only from the user.

Comment: It mean you always get one record from the database Am I right? If is it I think the problem is "Item::find()" you should use "Item::where()" then you can get all records to relevant item_code

Comment: It means I get all the messages from the user only. If there are answers from admin I don't get them when I use link like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Controller

```
public function details( $item_id ){

    $flags = Item::where('item_id',$item_id)->get();
    return view('details', compact('flags'));
}
```

In your view

```
foreach($flags as $flag):
    <a href="{{URL::to('replays/' . $flag->item_id.'/'.$flag->user_id)}}">Replay To User</a>
endforeach;
```

Comment: The query doesn't work like this. I need to use `report` and `unique` ... `...report->unique('user_id')`

Comment: according to your requirement you have to use "where" you can't achieve your requirement from "find" If I understood your question. Thank you.

Comment: I've added `Item` model to my question and function `report` which I need,

Comment: I've found workaround and manages to fix it. Thanks for the help and pointing me into right direction.